# Преобразование DataFrame ("Шахматка")

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot

Есть dataframe такого вида:

dt = pd.DataFrame({'project name':['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B'], 'task_point':[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'Text':['Red', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green','Red','Yellow', 'Red']})

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно привести к такому:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала думал сделать как сводную таблицу, но агрегировать по тексту никак не получится.
Сделать через group by тоже не получилось.

Подскажите, как сделать такую "шахматку"

Кортеж (project_name, task_point) - уникален. Повторений не может быть.

Comment: что-то у вас желаемый результат не соответствует исходным данным, либо вы не описали алгоритм агрегирования.

Comment: Решение, что Вы написали к моему примеру работает. А применительно к моему фрейму нет )) очень странно. пишет ошибку:  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [101], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.pivot(index='Название проекта', columns='Название задачи', values='Text')

А при pivot_table такая ошибка: 
utureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .mean, select on...

Comment: посмотрите внимательно ,  вам ответили правильно , только @strawdog  написал df   а у вас dt поменяйте и все заработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще это и делается с помощью сводных таблиц:

```
res = df.pivot(index = "project name", columns = "task_point", values="Text")
```

res:

```
task_point      1       2      3       4
project name                            
A             Red     Red    NaN     NaN
B             NaN  Yellow    NaN     Red
C             NaN     NaN  Green     NaN
D             NaN     NaN    NaN     Red
E             NaN     NaN    NaN  Yellow
```